# The same RegExp returns true and false alternatively. Why?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this `regexp`. And it returns `true` and `false` interchangeably. How it can be? How to fix the regexp? The goal is to "allow figures AND spaces only" (123 56 123).

```
var r = new RegExp("[0-9\s]{3,30}", "gi")
r.test("123454")
true
r.test("123454")
false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is use of global `g` flag which [causes internal state (`lastIndex` property) of `RegExp` object to be remembered across multiple invocations of `test` or `exec` methods.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex).

If you use take out `g` flag from your regex i.e.:

```
var r = new RegExp("[0-9\\s]{3,30}");
```

Then it will behave fine.

```
r.test("123454")
true
r.test("123454")
true
r.test("123454")
true
```

**PS:** `i` flag has no use and that can be  removed as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an anchored regex and also escape the backslash one more time. And don't use `g` modifier since the regex is anchored.

```
var r = new RegExp("^[0-9\\s]{3,30}$", "m")
```

Example:

```
> var r = new RegExp("^[0-9\\s]{3,30}$", "m")
undefined
> r.test("123454")
true
> r.test("123454")
true
```

**OR**

```
> var r = /^[0-9\s]{3,30}$/m;
undefined
> r.test("123454")
true
```

Answer (score 1):

try this regex https://regex101.com/r/jO0sX7/1

```
^[0-9\s]{3,30}$
```

or

```
^[\d\s]{3,30}$
```